# App.js to redirect to a module

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am debugging into a NODE JS application and I am very new to node js. I have a REST module file

**students.js**

```
module.exports = function (service) {

    /**
     * Retrives data from DB
     */
    service.get('/mobile/students', function (req, res) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                .status(200)
                .json(DBHelper.getAllStudents());
    });

    service.post('/mobile/students', function (req, res) {
        res.status(200).json(data);
    });
});
```

To run it locally I am using the following **app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var routes = require('./students');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!')
});

app.listen(3010, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3010!')
});
```

When I hit 
http://localhost:3010/students, I am hitting a 404.

How do I explicit route the path to the student modules?

Comment: I think you need to do `require('./students')(app)`  and then you will probably get your students on `http://localhost:3010/mobile/students` ?

Comment: Hi Codtex,   Thanks .  I think you are asking me to add     require('./students')    to app.js . But that didn't work .

Comment: I am sorry, My mistake require('./students') (app)  did worked.  Can you help me in understanding what it actually does ?

Comment: Hello mate, you already have this code there. I ask you to just change `var routes = require('./students');` to `require('./students')(app);`, because I see that from **students.js** you are exporting function that looks like accepting express app as argument

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `routes(app);`  line after `var routes = require('./students');` then Your routes will be mounted.. 
`http://localhost:3010/students` if use this it will prompt you again with 404 but if you use `http://localhost:3010/mobile/students` it will produce desire output..